# Iterate to check if column name is equal to another column's value

Tags: pandas, loops

Is there a way to iterate across a dataframe where if a column name is equal to another column's value to input a '1' into that specific cell.

For example:

```
[A]  [B]  [C]  
D
E
B
C
```

would translate to:

```
[A] [B] [C]
D
E
B   1   
C       1
```

The null values in B and c would simply be NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
df.fillna('').apply(lambda x : x.index==x.name).astype(int).replace(0,"")
Out[563]: 
      A  B  C
index        
D            
E            
B        1   
C           1
```